# How to reload the collectionview after dismiss a present modally view?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, frontend, viewcontroller

I have a tab bar with two tab bar item and I add a central addButton on it which can lead me to the adding items viewcontroller. Here is the setup of the middle button.

```
 func setupMiddleButton() {
    
    let tabBarHeight = tabBar.frame.size.height
    
   
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarHeight*1.5, height: tabBarHeight*1.5))
    var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
    
    menuButtonFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height/2 - tabBarHeight - 8

    menuButtonFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
    menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
    
    menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
    view.addSubview(menuButton)
    
    let largeConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
    let addIcon = UIImage(systemName: "plus", withConfiguration: largeConfiguration)
    menuButton.setImage((addIcon), for: .normal)
    
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@objc private func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
      let addVC = AddViewController()
      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addVC)
      
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "addEventSegue", sender: sender)
    

    
}
```

and I did this in one of my tab bar view to reloadData, but I found the collectionView unable to reload after I end editing and dismiss the present modally

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    lifeCollectionView.delegate = self
    lifeCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.fetchData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.lifeCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

What should I do to reload the collection view after I dismiss that present modally? Thank you so much!

Comment: `navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` will call `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @jawadAli should I make some change in the storyboard? Cuz after I implement this code, the presentation is still modal? and is there any ways I can reloadData not using viewWillAppear? Thx a lot.

Comment: yes .. through delegates and closures ...

Comment: let me know if you still face any difficulty

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve that delegate , closure and modalPresentation Style

**Way 1:**
if you add `navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` this will call `viewWillAppear` of the controller who presents controller and your reload method will get called

**Way 2: Delegate & Protocol**

Declare a protocol like the one below in Second Controller

```
protocol CallParent{
    func reloadCollection()
}
```

Declare a property to hold the reference of view controller confirming to this protocol in Second Controller

```
weak var myParent : CallParent?
```

Now call reloadCollection before dismiss

```
 if let parent = myParent {
    parent.reloadCollection()
}
```

Confirm first controller with CallParent protocol

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController,CallParent{
```

Then while calling segue

```
@objc private func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
      let addVC = AddViewController()
       addVC.myParent = self 
      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addVC)
      
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "addEventSegue", sender: sender)
    

    
}
```

**Way 3 :**  In your presented controller call dismiss function like this

```
 if let fvc = self.presentingViewController as? FirstController {

        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
             fvc.callReloadFunctionHere()
        }
    }
```

**Way 4:** Closure

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var onViewWillDisappear: (()->())?

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        onViewWillDisappear?()
    }
    ...
}
```

In FirstController

```
 @objc private func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
          let addVC = AddViewController()
              addVC.onViewWillDisappear = {
                // reload collection view here 
            }
          let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addVC)
          
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "addEventSegue", sender: sender)
        
    
        
    }
```

Comment: I used the way 3 u provide but I don't know why that fvc in my code seems always be like nil so the dismiss never run?

Comment: whats your firstViewController name ?

Comment: I used a tabBarViewController to manage the middle Large add button on the tabBar and I have two view controllers, which both have a collectionView inside, conform to some collectionView protocals to make the thing wok. I don't know whether that's the issue?

Comment: or is your firstViewController is navigation controller ?

Comment: I name one LifeViewController and another one WorkViewController

Comment: my recommendation is to use `way 4` its best suits your case

Comment: it's a tabBar View controller, but all of the controllers I embed them in navigationview controller

Comment: i'll try it now

Comment: yeah .. its best for navigation + tabbar case

Comment: I found the major issue of my code is when I create a new variable and want to reloadData of it in these methods, I always found it nil when unwrap, do you have any idea what may that problem be? Really Thx a lot for answering me.

Comment: Are you doing the same steps ? Assign that closure in present function

Comment: Assign that closure in menuPressAction ... as mention in my answer ...

Comment: If you assign it in menuPressAction function which is presenting modally ... will not leave your optional variable nil ...

Comment: I add a print statement inside the bracket of add VC.onViewWillDisappear = { } to test but nothing was running. The nil unwrapping stuff doesn't come out tho

Answer (score 0):

Set your collection view datasource, delegate and reload only in `viewDidLoad`. 
You don't need to use `viewWillAppear` to reload your collectionView every time!

Use **delegates** to pass messages.

```swift
protocol ContentChangedDelegate: class {
    func itemAdded()
}
```

Within `AddViewController` add the below variable

```swift
weak var delegate: ContentChangedDelegate? = nil
```

Set your the UIViewController subclass instance where the `lifeCollectionView` exists as delegate for `AddViewController`.

```swift
let addVC = AddViewController()
addVC.delegate = self
//push or present addVC
```

Conform your view controller to the `ContentChangedDelegate` protocol and within the `itemAdded` method you can reload your collection view.

Call `delegate?.itemAdded()` after adding your item in `AddViewController`. This would call the method in your listVC and it should update immediately.

Comment: what's if I presentSegue the addVC in a TabBarController and have my lifeCollectionView in another specific controller? I have them seperate bc i want to customize the Large add Button

Comment: I have added a code snippet here. Set the delegate in prepare for segue. **Snippet**: https://pastebin.com/DkxmXfbZ

Comment: Make sure to call `delegate?.itemAdded()` from **AddViewController** after setting the delegate to it calls the itemAdded method in your main VC.

Comment: What if the delegate is always found nil when implicitly unwrapped?

Comment: That means the delegate isn't getting set correctly before you show the viewcontroller. Did you try setting the delegate in prepare for seague as I have shown in the pastebin link in the above comment? Is anything being printed?

Comment: I change the delegate to a static one to make it work? Is it a normal case? And I'm wondering is it only going to be that tabBarController (which i have the performSegue method in) can run the delegate method? Cuz I have two other viewController also conform to the delegate but they just don't work?